Magento 2 - Access to XMLHttpRequest - /adminhtml/Magento/spectrum/en_US/js-translation.json has been blocked
Currently we are using magento 2.4.6-p6, we are recently noticing below issue in the console, while opening the cms blocks / cms pages from admin.
Access to XMLHttpRequest at 'https://website.com/static/version1721183017/adminhtml/Magento/spectrum/en_US/js-translation.json' from origin 'null' has been blocked by CORS policy: Response to preflight request doesn't pass access control check: It does not have HTTP ok status.
and we are not able to save the blocks/pages whenever this error coming in the console.
how we can fix this issue?
thanks!!

You can try applying this patch ACSD-60169_2.4.6-p6.patch
https://drive.google.com/file/d/1kHfAPB_NSqFEHlNoRDrBULJ8VKdmTP18/view

Is there a more official source for this? I don't think people should click on random Google Drive links...

I think it’s not yet been published. That’s my upload and It works on my project at least.
